# How to suppress the single quote character in an echo command?

Tags: bash

If I execute this command directly from CLI, I don't have any problem:

```
~ # apt autoremove 1>$- 2>$-
~ #
```

But if I call it from a script I have some errors:
Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
NOVERBOSE='1>$- 2>$-'
apt autoremove $(echo ${NOVERBOSE})
```

And here is the output:

```
~ # /bin/bash -x test2.sh
+ NOVERBOSE='1>$- 2>$-'
++ echo '1>$-' '2>$-'
+ apt autoremove '1>$-' '2>$-'
Reading package lists ... Done
Building the dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done
E: Unable to find package 1> $
E: Unable to find a package matching the regular expression "1> $"
E: Unable to find package 2> $
E: Unable to find a package matching the regular expression "2> $"
```

I don't understand why echo add some singles quotes around each part of the variable.

Comment: I have never seen that `1>$- 2>$-`. Can I know what it does?

Comment: That's not going to work anyway; redirections are processed before parameter expansions, so you are just passing unexpected arguments to `apt`.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a description of why the original code doesn't work with a discussion of best-practice alternatives, and [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for a discussion of why using `eval` to work around it is a dangerous habit to be in.

Comment: @RobertoManfreda, that looks like the OP meant to redirect to `&-` (which closes the file descriptors) but got the syntax wrong. `$-` is a list of currently active shell flags, so `>$-` redirects to a file whose name depends on those flags. Closing stdout and stderr is bad practice anyhow; can cause spurious failures, safer to redirect to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Ty @Charles Duffy .. great explanation (as always) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NOVERBOSE` should be a flag that indicates the *desire* to suppress output, not the syntax to do so. You then test the value and redirect output (or not) as appropriate.

```
if [[ $NOVERBOSE = [Yy]* ]]; then  # e.g., y, Y, yes, Yes, etc
    apt autoremove > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
else
    apt autoremove
fi
```

If you don't like running `apt` "twice" like this, you can redirect to `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` explicitly as a no-op redirection.

```
if [[ $NOVERBOSE = [Yy]* ]]; then
  out=/dev/null
  err=/dev/null
else
  out=/dev/stdout
  err=/dev/stderr
fi

apt autoremove > "$out" 2> "$err"
```

Comment: As always thank you for you reply @chepner. I was looking for a switch that I can use or not to print stdout and stderr and this is exactly what you proposed!

Answer (score 2):

`echo` isn't adding quotes, that's just how the `-x` option shows where each argument begins and ends.

The problem is that I/O redirections are not processed after expanding variables. You need to use `eval` to re-parse the line.

```
eval "apt autoremove $NOVERBOSE"
```

Comment: While true, this is a bad approach to conditionally muting the output.